# how to export indexes of selected faces to an txt file

Tags: faces

I want to render some selected face using program.
But i don't know the indexes of the faces that i want to render.
Is there a good method to output the indexes of selected faces to a file?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Python:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

with open('/PATHTOFILE/selected_faces.txt', 'w') as file:
    for f in obj.data.polygons:
        if f.select:
            file.write(f'{f.index} ')
```

Run it in [Text Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html). Paste it into new text file and press run (button with play icon) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.  But could you please explain where to run these script?

Comment: In text editor. Paste it into new text file and run (button with play icon)

Comment: It's awesome. Thank you for your detailed perfect solution.